# How to stub async action in componentDidMount for react redux connected component test using Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

I have a simple connected component that, when loaded, builds the user details by calling an async action and then displays those details from state.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loadUserDetails } from '../actions/user';

class ShowUserDetailsLite extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadUserDetails();
  }

  render() {
    const { userDetails } = this.props;

    const handleClickEdit = () => {
      history.push(editProfilePath());
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="email">
          {userDetails.email_address}
        </div>
        <div className="name">
          {userDetails.first_name} {userDetails.last_name}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ShowUserDetailsLite.propTypes = {
  loadUserDetails: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  userDetails: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  loadUserDetails,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const userDetails = state.user.details;
  return { userDetails };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShowUserDetailsLite);
```

To start, I'd like to test that my component is displaying the correct information from state, so I have the following test.

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import React from 'react'
import Provider from 'react-redux';
import ShowUserDetailsLite from '../../components/ShowUserDetailsLite'

describe('ShowUserDetailsLite component', () => {
  it('displays the current user', () => {
    const mockStore = configureStore();
    let store = mockStore({
      user: {
        details: {
          email_address: 'test@test.com',
          first_name: 'First',
          last_name: 'Last',
        }
      },
    });
    let wrapper = shallow(<ShowUserDetailsLite store={store} loadUserDetails={jest.fn()}/>).dive()
    expect(wrapper.find('.email').text()).to.eql('test@test.com')
  })
})
```

When I run this test with the `componentDidMount` function commented out it works great, the state is read and the correct information is displayed, but when I run the test including the `componentDidMount` function the test attempts to call the function and I get the following error:

```
 FAIL  app/tests/components/ShowUserDetailsLite.test.js
  ShowUserDetailsLite component
    ✕ displays the current user (32ms)

  ● ShowUserDetailsLite component › displays the current user

    ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

      16 |
      17 | export function loadUserDetails() {
    > 18 |   return async dispatch => {
         |   ^
      19 |     try {
      20 |       const res = await axios.get(`/${window.realm}/api/userDetails`);
      21 |       dispatch({ type: SET_USER_DETAILS, data: res.data });
```

At this stage I don't care about testing the loadUserDetails function so I simply want to stub it. I understood that to do that you simply need to pass the function in as a property, which I've attempted to do by passing in a jest function:

```
let wrapper = shallow(<ShowUserDetailsLite store={store} loadUserDetails={jest.fn()}/>).dive()
```

But still I'm getting the error. How do I properly stub async actions called in componentdidmount for connected component tests?

Answer (score 0):

I come probably to late but i ended up here struggeling too with the same problem ,after digging for 2 days i founded that :

Since you wrap your component with Connect you need to pass your stubbed props function  to the child component

Your can export your component without the HOC connect

```
export ShowUserDetailsLite
```

then import it

```
import {ShowUserDetailsLite} from ...
```

And now you have a shallowed component without connect you can directly pass the props like the users and the loadUserDetails mocked

To be more complete with the original question :

## How to stub componentDidMount

When you `mount` or `shallow` your component you will fire componentDidMount .

**With shallow**

for  `shallow` rendering your can use the option `{disableLifecycleMethods:true}`

```
 wrapper = shallow(
          <Stats {...props} />, {disableLifecycleMethods:true}
        )
```

**With mount**

If you want to use `mount` for rendering you need to stub componentDidMount doing this way :

```
jest.spyOn(YOUCOMPONENT.prototype, 'componentDidMount').mockImplementation();
```

then you mount your component

```
wrapper = mount(
      <Stats {...props} />
    )
```

And now you can have access to the methods if you want to stub a method called in the componentDidMount:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'myMethod').mockImplementation(() => {//do stuff})
```